# PHP price numbers and converting to string with comma

Tags: php

I am trying to convert price in PHP to use it in different functions of website, but can not make it work properly for every case I need.

I have webshop where prices as `$total_price` can be:

```
a). 650

b). 1260.2

c). 17.55
```

I need to convert them in two different types/forms for usage in different places.
**FORM 1: price needs to look like**

```
a). 65000

b). 126020

c). 1755
```

**FORM 2: price needs to look like**

```
a). 650,00

b). 1260,20

c). 17,55
```

I have tried different things but non of them gave me desired results (FORM 1 and FORM 2) as output.
As you can see, "." is used for decimal separator and app prices must be pushed to 2 decimal places.

Does anyone know the best was to do this conversion properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use number_format function in php

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php

form 1

```
    $a = 650;
    $b = number_format($a, 2, ",", "");
    // display : 650,00
```

form 2

```
    $a = 650;
    $b = number_format($a, 2, "", "");
    // display : 65000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `money_format()` function.
Link with examples: [money_format() examples](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_money_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use number_format($yourNumber);